# Is it possible to demolish one of the rail tracks in a station, and not all of them?

Tags: openttd

Sometimes I want to demolish just one line of rail station in a big station. However when you demolish it, all of the rail stations go away. Is it possible to just get rid of one station at a time?

Here's what I mean. In the pic below, I want to demolish only the rail station that's in red, because I don't use it. I don't want to get rid of all of the other ones, because I do use them. Can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to select 'build station', then 'remove' (the bulldozer, not the bomb)

[image]

Drag over the station area you need removed

[image]

and now one of the station is removed

[image]

you can then proceed to remove the track left behind

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I've just been using the bomb for everything. Didn't even notice the bulldozer icon.

Comment: @lemontwist You can use the bulldozer with tracks, signals and other things to selectively remove them without removing other things on the same square

Comment: That is awesome. I always delete the full tracks and stations, and now I don't have to. Thanks!